# Chart.JS - Implement multi-bar chart

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, chart.js, angular9

I implemented Chart.JS in my Angular 9 application. The chart is not rendered as expected.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.smdashboardservice.fetchSmDashboardData().subscribe(response=>{

    //let data = response.data
    let data = [
      {"label":"Application","sublabel":"Nice","count":2},
      {"label":"Application","sublabel":"poor","count":1},
      {"label":"Channels","sublabel":"Quality","count":2},
      {"label":"Customer Care","sublabel":"support","count":2}
    ]

    this.barChartLabels = Object.keys(data);
    this.barChartLabels.forEach(label => {
      this.barChartData[0].data.push(data[label]['count']);
    });

  })
}
```

**Current code giving chart**

[image]

**But I am expecting like this**

[image]

[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bar-chart-in-angular-chart-js-stacked-mk4scd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare the datasets which categorize the `sublabel`.

Each dataset should contain the values with the length of x-axis category (`label`), which is 3.

```
let labels = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.label))];
let subLabels = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.sublabel))];
let subLabelDatasets = subLabels.map((x) => {
  let datasets = [];

  for (let label of labels) {
    datasets.push(
      data.find((y) => y.label == label && y.sublabel == x)?.count || 0
    );
  }

  return {
    label: x,
    data: datasets,
  };
});

this.barChartLabels = labels;
this.barChartData = subLabelDatasets;
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bar-chart-in-angular-chart-js-stacked-5emgrj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Alternative: `subLabelDatasets` can be simplified as:

```
let subLabelDatasets = subLabels.map((x) => ({
  label: x,
  data: labels.map(
    (label) =>
      data.find((y) => y.label == label && y.sublabel == x)?.count || 0
  )
}));
```

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538190/angular-9-chart-js-stacked-bar-chart-with-multiple-bars

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779518/angular-9-chart-js-bar-chart-click-event