# Angular 9 Chart.js stacked bar chart with multiple bars

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I implemented Chart.js in my Angular 9 application. There expect chart values are not coming.

I have an API response in that I want to make `barChartData` as below mentioned way [stackblitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-wpq6xn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

This is my API response:

```
let data = [
  { operatorName: 'MBC', label: 'Application', subLabel: 'Positive', count: 1 },
  { operatorName: 'MBC', label: 'Channels', subLabel: 'Negative', count: -1 },
  { operatorName: 'MBC', label: 'Customer Care', subLabel: 'Negative', count: -1 },
  { operatorName: 'MBC', label: 'Customer Care', subLabel: 'Positive', count: 1 },
  { operatorName: 'OSEN+', label: 'Application', subLabel: 'Negative', count: -1 },
  { operatorName: 'OSEN+', label: 'Application', subLabel: 'Positive', count: 1 },
  { operatorName: 'OSEN+', label: 'Channels', subLabel: 'Positive', count: 1},
  { operatorName: 'OSEN+', label: 'Customer Care', subLabel: 'Positive', count: 1 }
];
```

I want to set `barChartData` with the API response.

Expected Data set:

```
this.barChartLabels = ['Application', 'Customer Care', 'Package'];
this.barChartData = [
  {
    label: 'OSEN+ Passtive',
    type: 'bar',
    stack: 'OSEN+',
    data: [30, 31, 23],
  },
  {
    label: 'OSEN+ Negative',
    type: 'bar',
    stack: 'OSEN+',
    data: [-15, -16],
  },
  {
    label: 'MBC Passtive',
    type: 'bar',
    stack: 'MBC',
    data: [20, 21],
  },
  {
    label: 'MBC Negative',
    type: 'bar',
    stack: 'MBC',
    data: [-10, -11],
  },
];
```

I tried to implement the logic here:

```
let labels = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.label))];
let operators = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.operatorName))];
let subLabels = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.subLabel))];
let subLabelDatasets = subLabels.map((x) => {
  let datasets = [];
  let opratorlabes = [];
  for (let label of labels) {
    datasets.push(
      data.find((y) => y.label == label && y.subLabel == x)?.count || 0
    );
  }

  //console.log(data)
  return {
    label: opratorlabes,
    data: datasets,
  };
});
```

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare to the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76189292/8017690) I have written, the concept is similar.

For the `subLabels`, since you need to group the data by `operatorName` and `subLabel`, you need to distinct the group for the objects containing these 2 properties.

While in the `dataset` of each object in `subLabelDatasets`, you can find the value by getting the `value` based on `label`, `operatorName`, and `subLabel` from the `data` array.

```
let labels = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.label))];
let subLabels = data.reduce((acc, cur: any) => {
  if (
    acc.findIndex(
      (x) =>
        x.operatorName == cur.operatorName && x.subLabel == cur.subLabel
    ) == -1
  )
    acc.push({ operatorName: cur.operatorName, subLabel: cur.subLabel });

  return acc;
}, [] as { operatorName: string; subLabel: string }[]);

let subLabelDatasets = subLabels.map((x) => {
  let datasets = [];

  for (let label of labels) {
    datasets.push(
      data.find(
        (y) =>
          y.label == label &&
          y.subLabel == x.subLabel &&
          y.operatorName == x.operatorName
      )?.count || 0
    );
  }

  return {
    label: x.operatorName + ' ' + x.subLabel,
    data: datasets,
    stack: x.operatorName,
    type: 'bar',
  };
});

this.barChartLabels = labels;
this.barChartData = subLabelDatasets;
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-tqyhsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)